# automapper pass profile as an method parameter

Tags: c#, automapper, aspose

I have columns like this in excel :

| ProductID | SomeExplanation | AnotherColumn1 | AnotherColumn2 | AnotherColumn3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 6 | A | 65465 |
| 2 | Y | 5 | B | 6556 |
| 3 | Z | 7 | C | 65465 |

I need to convert this excel to list of columns and these columns must be an dictonary. And the dicitonary must have key values (like ProductID,SomeExplanation,AnotherColumn1 ,AnotherColumn2 ,  AnotherColumn3 ) and list values(for exmaple ProductID key's values : 1,2,3).

I am using aspose library and I am taking values(every cells) as an object so I need an configuration file to convert this object type to spefic types like int,string,double etc.

.This is my method but It creating the values as an object :

```
public List<Dictionary<string, List<object>>> GenerateExcelDictionary(Worksheet worksheet) 

{
    
var columnMax = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn;
var rowMax = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow;
var myExcelContainer = new List<Dictionary<string, List<object>>>();
var columnKeyWithValues = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>(); // I want to use spefic types instead ofobject


for (int column = 0; column < columnMax; column++)
{
    var columnName = worksheet.Cells[0, column].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    
    columnKeyWithValues.Add(columnName, new List<object>());
}

for (int column = 0; column < columnMax; column++)
{
    var values = new List<object>();
    for (int row = 1; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        values.Add(worksheet.Cells[row, column]);
    }
    columnKeyWithValues[worksheet.Cells[0, column].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty)] = values;
}
myExcelContainer.Add(columnKeyWithValues);

return myExcelContainer;
}
```

in this method  I am getting the column values as an object but I want to use more spefic type(like int, string,double).

So I need to somekind a mapper or generic type(I think both of them required) but I could not make.

My general question how to inform method the types that I want to create in List and with its key values. And how can I pass automapper configuration to method ?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Thank you so much <3 , I will look when I return from speaking club. If I will have a question I will add a new comment. Thank you again :)